# Regular expression for might have a space

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to look for a regular expession for might have a space.  I am searching for occurences of

```
word1word2
```

and

```
word1 word2
```

I try:

```
grep "word1[ +]word2" mylog.txt
```

But this does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do the words that might have a space (or not) all end in a number, or have some other recognisable pattern? If not you are going to need a dictionary, and a regex won't cut it.

Comment: `word1[ +]word2` means word1 and word2 separated by a space or plus, is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
grep "word1 \?word2" mylog.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
grep -E "word1 ?word2" mylog.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Following regex should do the trick:

```
x *y
```

It will check for any number of spaces between x and y.

Answer (score 0):

Try `"word1\s*word2"`.

- usually means 'at least one, but also many occurences'.
- means 'any amount of occurences, even zero'
  \s is the placeholder for whitespace characters (can also be a tab).

If you would only want zero or one space you could try `"word1\s{0,1}word2"`

Btw: the + or * would follow after the brackets: `[ ]+`